# gpg physically protecting private key file

Tags: gnupg

I'm just getting started with GPG. I've created a key pair and now have several .gpg files:

```
drwx------  2 jason jason  4096 Feb 11 21:10 ./
drwx------ 90 jason jason 45056 Feb 11 20:49 ../
-rw-------  1 jason jason  9398 Feb 11 20:49 gpg.conf
-rw-rw-r--  1 jason jason  2316 Feb 11 21:10 mypk
-rw-------  1 jason jason  1633 Feb 11 20:52 pubring.gpg
-rw-------  1 jason jason  1633 Feb 11 20:52 pubring.gpg~
-rw-------  1 jason jason   600 Feb 11 20:52 random_seed
-rw-------  1 jason jason  1794 Feb 11 20:52 secring.gpg
-rw-------  1 jason jason  1280 Feb 11 20:52 trustdb.gpg
```

Am I correct to understand that secring.gpg is my private key? This file is protected by my passphrase, right? Is it ok to just keep this file on my machine? Should I move it somewhere more secure (say a thumb drive)?

Comment: In the future, consider posting questions like these to [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Feel free to move it. I've posted to other stackexchanges before and had those posts moved here, so I never know what the best place is. Plus there is a 235 other posts tagged GPG so I figured it was an OK place.

Comment: At each SO page, there is an [FAQ] which describes what to post here. Your question is definitely about administration (or security), not about programming, so it's off topic here. The other 235 posts tagged GPG are mostly about embedding it in PHP and other programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct to understand that secring.gpg is my private key?

From `man gpg`:

```
~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
       The secret keyring.  You should backup this file.
```

---

> This file is protected by my passphrase, right?

If you set one, yes. Actually not the file itself is protected, but each contained key can be (you can have multiple private keys in your secret keyring).

---

> Is it ok to just keep this file on my machine? Should I move it somewhere more secure (say a thumb drive)?

This depends on your needs and trust in your machine.

- Do you have special security needs, share your machine or expect it to be hacked/stolen/...? Better put it on an external device and then reference it using `--secret-keyring /path/to/secring.gpg` whenever using `gpg` or put it into your `gpg.conf`: `secret-keyring /path/to/secring.gpg`.
- Do you trust the integrity of your computer, possibly even encrypted your files on it? Will you have to use your secret key a lot? Better keep the file on your hard drive as this saves hassles with using `gpg`.

For putting your key on a separate device, think of using an [OpenPGP card](http://wiki.debian.org/Smartcards/OpenPGP). Using one, your secret key will never leave that card (for signing and decrypting) but for backup purpose. Definitely increases nerd factor, too. ;)